# FireStore - Multiple isEqualTo/== query on a single field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am aware we are allowed one in-equality filter on a field, per query. However, my question is, is it possible to use the `iEqualTo` query on the same field multiple times?

An example of what I mean:

```
var price = 100
query.whereField"price", isEqualTo: price-1) - 99
query.whereField"price", isEqualTo: price-2) - 98
query.whereField"price", isEqualTo: price-3) - 97
```

Would this return all  items where the price field is ranging from 99-97? Or would the final/last query on this field only be interpreted so only returning where price is 97? I've already used my one quota of range/in-equality filters so this may be a viable solution, for now.

I have a large dataset where I need to query multiple fields, I can do this on the client side, however, I'm trying to limit as much data that can be read as possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do what you want:

1. With a [range query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators): `ref.where("price", ">=", 97).where("price", "M=", 99)`
2. With an [`in` query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any): `ref.where("price", "in", [97, 98, 99])`

For more information on both, see the Firebase documentation on [queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).

Comment: The range query, I have already used. I need to use it on multiple fields. And my values are stored in their own separate fields

Comment: Ah, in that case: nope, that's not possible. Values in Firestore queries have to be literal, and can't be a reference to another field. The typical workaround would be to run such a comparison of the fields when updating the doc, and then store the result in a field you can check with a literal value. So a field `priceIsPrice1: true` that indicates that the `price` value is the same as the `price1` value.

Comment: Ahhh. thank you. I've read about merging queries, however, this for me would be useless. I appreciate the reply! Thank you.